# Compiling Old Version of Crypto++, Problems with md5.h and Templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, crypto++

I am working on getting a piece of legacy software to build with gcc 4.7 on Debian stable (which currently also requires libstdc++5 3.2 for some reason), and currently g++ is hung up on crypto++'s md5.h

My c++ skills are rusty, and I've been staring at this for a couple days now. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this?

The full source of the version of cryto++ I'm using: 
http://www.filedropper.com/cryptolegacy

**the error:**

```
compiling md5.cpp (g++)
compiling md5.cpp (g++)
In file included from md5.cpp:5:0:
md5.h:10:32: error: expected template-name before '<' token
md5.h:10:32: error: expected '{' before '<' token
md5.h:10:32: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token
md5.cpp:109:1: error: expected '}' at end of input
```

**md5.h**

```
#ifndef CRYPTOPP_MD5_H
#define CRYPTOPP_MD5_H

#include "iterhash.h"

NAMESPACE_BEGIN(CryptoPP)

/// <a href="http://www.weidai.com/scan-mirror/md.html#MD5">MD5</a>
/** 128 Bit Hash */
class MD5 : public IteratedHash<word32, false, 64>
{
public:
     enum {DIGESTSIZE = 16};
     MD5() : IteratedHash<word32, false, 64>(DIGESTSIZE) {Init();}
     static void Transform(word32 *digest, const word32 *data);

protected:
    void Init();
    void vTransform(const word32 *data) {Transform(digest, data);}
};

NAMESPACE_END

#endif
```

Comment: What is the definition of IteratedHash?

Comment: Good question - I believe it is defined in iterhash.h but have yet to find it there or elsewhere.

Comment: I added a link above to the full source I'm using. http://www.filedropper.com/cryptolegacy

Comment: I have - this is literally all my predecessor gave me, without having to expose the wrapper that utilizes the built libraries once crypto++ succeeds. See the linked filedropper zip, it has all the crypto++ source I am using.

Comment: No file droppings please

Comment: Then what would you suggest? You seem to be trolling so far.

Comment: I'm not trolling, I'm just telling you the rules of the site.

Comment: *"The full source of the version of cryto++ I'm using: http://www.filedropper.com/cryptolegacy"* - Crypto++ provides its older versions, and its not clear to me why you would use something offered by a third party. For example, you can use [www.cryptopp.com/crypto42.zip](http://www.cryptopp.com/crypto42.zip) for the Crypto++ 4.2 download. Regardless, you should state which version of Crypto++ you are using.

Comment: I believe it is version 5 or earlier give or take - the code is inherited and I was just posting my question based on what I have available to me.

Comment: @ilikenwf - Check the README for the version. Then, visit [Crypto++ Legacy Versions](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Legacy_Download).

Comment: Will do. I am on the mailing list now.